Python-Polars: Create pairwise elements of two lists
In Python Polars I am trying to "group" two lists together, for example in a Pl.Struct, removing the group when one of the elements is Null. For example, given this DataFrame:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Movie": [[None, "IT",]],
    "Count": [[30, 27]],
})

shape: (1, 2)
┌──────────────┬───────────┐
│ Movie        ┆ Count     │
│ ---          ┆ ---       │
│ list[str]    ┆ list[i64] │
╞══════════════╪═══════════╡
│ [null, "IT"] ┆ [30, 27]  │
└──────────────┴───────────┘

I would like to get the result below:

shape: (1, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ data      │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {"IT",27} │
└───────────┘


However, the challenge I am finding in this case is that I need to do it in a single context (i.e. in a single with_columns). Is it possible?

df.with_columns(
    pl.struct(
        pl.col("Movie", "Count").list.gather(
            pl.col("Movie").list.eval(pl.element().is_not_null().arg_true())
        )
        .list.first()
    )
    .alias("data")
)

shape: (1, 3)
┌──────────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ Movie        ┆ Count     ┆ data      │
│ ---          ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ list[str]    ┆ list[i64] ┆ struct[2] │
╞══════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ [null, "IT"] ┆ [30, 27]  ┆ {"IT",27} │
└──────────────┴───────────┴───────────┘


Thanks! This works exactly as intended in a single context. Moreover, removing list.first I can apply it to longer lists and Nulls in different positions.

If you have the invariant that all lists have equal lengths:
(
    pl.DataFrame({
        "Movie": [[None, "IT",]],
        "Count": [[30, 27]],
    }).select(
        pl.all().explode()   # make a row per element pair
    ).drop_nulls()           # remove the null entries
     .select(
         pl.struct(pl.all()) # pack as struct
     )
)


shape: (1, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ Movie     │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {"IT",27} │
└───────────┘



Thank you very much for the response! In this case, I need to give jqurious response as my preferred option, as it does it in the same single context.
